# Fibonacci find the nth term Ruby

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I understand how fibonacci works but I need an explanation as to why this code works with `fib` in it vs `fib` without

```
def fib(n)
  return 1 if n <= 2
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
end
```

the code above gives the correct answer with `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`

BUT why does this code below not work?

```
def fib(n)
  return 1 if n <= 2
  return (n-1) + (n-2)
end
```

Comment: Because t's a completely different mathematical formula.  Why would that work?

Comment: can you please explain how it is different? by putting fib in the formula works and why it doesn't below

Comment: Try it for `fib(3)`.  If you cannot do that, then you don't have a programming question. You have a math problem.

Comment: @kbob How would you calculate `fib(5)` manually i.e. using pen and paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, welcome to the recursion man !

From now, i bet you always use a function as follow:

```
function something()
{
   //do_something
   return (something)
}
```

It's called iterative function, start and return of the function
But fibonnacci is good example to introduce the concept of recursion!
If you understand fibonnacci you realize that a value is provided by previous value
n + 1 = n / 2  it's a suite.
With that in mind, a function can call it self , yep you heard me,

```
function something()
{
  something();
}
```

this bit of code will call something forever until you get the famous error "stack overflow" (this website name comes from this error) but you will understand why later.

For now focus on the fact that fib will call it self n times depends on the value you want.

so by removing de `return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)` by `return (n-1) + (n-2)` you only execute this function "once", take this example, for fib if you need to call fib function 5 times but you called fib only once, you failed, that's not what you are asked for.

Thus, calling the same function inside the same one, you can have a taste of what is recursion, take a look on google, and test it !